# How can I select id which have 'Red' and at the same time 'Black'?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to write a simple `pl/sql` or `mssql`

For selecting the `car id` which is *red* and at the same time *black*.

**sample:**

```
ID | Color  
 1 | Red
 1 | Black
 2 | Brown
 2 | Red
 3 | Black
 3 | Yellow
```

**What i want is:**

```
ID
1
```

Comment: Is this for sql server or oracle?

Comment: @JensSchauder . . . "mssql" refers to SQL Server and "pl/sql" refers to Oracle.  The OP apparently wants either.

Comment: How about 3 rows with black/red/green?

Comment: @JensSchauder It s just for oracle, I edited my question

Comment: @GordonLinoff It s just for oracle, I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a SQL standard way that works in either database:

```
select id
from sample s
group by id
having sum(case when color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when color = 'black' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that match one of the colors.  Only `id`s that have each color will be included in the final result set.

EDIT:

You can add `where color in ('red', 'black')` before the `group by`.  Depending on the data and indexes, this could significantly improve the performance of the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID
FROM YourTable
WHERE Color IN ('Red','Black')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: I will try and turn back ou

Answer (score 1):

This will select only the ids:

```
select id 
    from mytable 
    where color in ('Red', 'Black')
    group by id
    having count(color) =2
```

Use it as an inner select to get colors as well.

```
select id, color
where color in ('Red', 'Black')
from mytable where id in (
    select id 
    from mytable 
    where color in ('Red', 'Black')
    group by id
    having count(color) =2
)
```

Comment: what is the different from lamak answer?

Comment: He assumed the table is named 'yourtable', while I assumed it is named 'mytabl' :-)

Answer (score 1):

For pl/sql, [a subselect using `IN` is just fine](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/30/in-vs-join-vs-exists-oracle/) with appropriate indexes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM   yourTable
WHERE  Color = 'Black' AND Id IN
       (SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM yourTable WHERE Color = 'Red')
```

And apparently, [for SQL Server as well](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/).

The take-away from the articles (always read them, though, [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) is one heck of a DB guy and a fun writer as well) is that `IN` may *look* inefficient, but it isn't necessarily on modern engines.

Comment: the distinct in the subselect is superfluous.

Comment: @JensSchauder: Thanks. On both engines? I've never really been sure... :-) I mean, I'd certainly *hope* so...

Comment: don't know about sql-server. But 100% for oracle. I have it actually seen causing performance issues, because it triggered a completely useless sort.

Comment: @JensSchauder: That's interesting, Quassnoi usually backs this stuff up with really quite thorough research and published data (see the links for detail).

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID from YourTable T1

where exists (select * from YourTable where ID = T1.ID and Color = 'Red')
  and exists (select * from YourTable where ID = T1.ID and Color = 'Black')
```